# Getting Touble With Isometric Projection In Python

Tags: python, numpy, opengl

[image]

I am trying to generate Shape II from Shape I, and I have created the following code.

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
import numpy as np

vertices = np.array([
    [0, 0, 0, 1],
    [0.707, -0.408, 0, 1],
    [0, -0.816, 0, 1],
    [-0.707, -0.408, 0, 1],
    [-0.707, 0.408, 0, 1],
    [0, 0.816, 0, 1],
    [0.707, 0.408, 0, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 1]
], dtype=np.float64)

edges = [
    (0, 1),
    (1, 2),
    (2, 3),
    (3, 4),
    (4, 5),
    (5, 6),
    (6, 7),
    (3, 0),
    (4, 7),
    (7, 2),
    (6, 1),
    (0, 5)
]

axis_vertices = np.array([
    [0, 0, 0, 1],
    [4, 0, 0, 1],
    [0, 4, 0, 1],
    [0, 0, 4, 1]
], dtype=np.float64)

axis_edges = [
    (0, 1),
    (0, 2),
    (0, 3)
]

def multiply_matrix_vector(matrix, vector):

    result = np.zeros(matrix.shape[0])

    for i in range(matrix.shape[0]):
        temp_result = np.dot(matrix[i, :], vector)
        
        list(result)[i] = temp_result
  

    return result


def draw_cube():
    glBegin(GL_LINES)
    glColor3f(1, 1, 1)
    for edge in edges:
        for vertex in edge:
            glVertex3fv(vertices[vertex][:3])
    glEnd()

def draw_axes():
    glBegin(GL_LINES)
    glColor3f(1, 0, 0)
    glVertex3fv(axis_vertices[0][:3])
    glVertex3fv(axis_vertices[1][:3])
    glColor3f(0, 1, 0)
    glVertex3fv(axis_vertices[0][:3])
    glVertex3fv(axis_vertices[2][:3])
    glColor3f(0, 0, 1)
    glVertex3fv(axis_vertices[0][:3])
    glVertex3fv(axis_vertices[3][:3])
    glEnd()

def set_perspective_matrix(fov, aspect, near, far):
    f = 1.0 / np.tan(np.radians(fov) / 2.0)
    perspective_matrix = np.array([
        [f / aspect, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, f, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, (far + near) / (near - far), (2 * far * near) / (near - far)],
        [0, 0, -1, 0]
    ])
    glLoadMatrixd(perspective_matrix.transpose())

def main():
    pygame.init()
    display = (800, 600)
    pygame.display.set_mode(display, DOUBLEBUF | OPENGL)
    
    set_perspective_matrix(45, (display[0] / display[1]), 0.1, 50.0)

    glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, -5)
    draw_cube()
    pygame.display.flip()

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        
        glPushMatrix()

        # Translate along the x-axis
        translation_matrix = np.array([
            [1, 0, 0, 1.5],
            [0, 1, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 1, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 1]
        ])
        global vertices
        vertices = np.dot(vertices, translation_matrix.T)

        # Perform isometric projection
        isometric_matrix = np.array([
            [0.707, -0.408, 0.577, 0],
            [0, 0.816, 0.577, 0],
            [-0.707, -0.408, 0.577, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 1]
        ])
        vertices = multiply_matrix_vector(isometric_matrix, vertices.T).T

        draw_axes()
        glPopMatrix()

        draw_cube()
        pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.time.wait(10)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

However, I encountered an error while making adjustments:

Line 49

```
result[i] = temp_result
~~~~~~^^^
```

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. When I make the following modification:

`list(result)[i] = temp_result`

I get a new error:
line 64,

```
glVertex3fv(vertices[vertex][:3])
```

IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.

Could you please assist me?

Comment: `temp_result` is an array, because `vector` is not a single vector, but an array of vectors (`vertices `)

Comment: Why do you specify a perspective projection matrix if you want to create an isometric projection? Why do you encode the isometric projection in the vertex coordinates if you want to generate the isometric projection using matrix transformations?

Comment: Shape 1 is a mesh with 2D coordinates. You cannot convert flat lines into a 3D mesh as the information of one dimension is missing.

Answer (score 0):

1. Why do you specify a perspective projection matrix if you want to create an isometric projection?
2. Why do you encode the isometric projection in the vertex coordinates if you want to generate the isometric projection using matrix transformations?

Do not encode the isometric projection in the vertex coordinates:

```py
vertices = np.array([
    (-1,-1,-1, 1), ( 1,-1,-1, 1), ( 1, 1,-1, 1), (-1, 1,-1, 1), 
    (-1,-1, 1, 1), ( 1,-1, 1, 1), ( 1, 1, 1, 1), (-1, 1, 1, 1)], dtype=np.float64)
edges = [(0,1), (1,2), (2,3), (3,0), (4,5), (5,6), (6,7), (7,4), (0,4), (1,5), (2,6), (3,7)]
```

Use an orthogrphic projection:

```py
def set_orthographic_matrix(l, r, b, t, n, f):
    m = np.array([
        [2/(r-l), 0, 0, -(r+l)/(r-l)],
        [0, 2/(t-b), 0, -(t+b)/(t-b)],
        [0, 0, -2/(f-n), -(f+n)/(f-n)],
        [0, 0, 0, 1]
    ])
    glLoadMatrixd(m.T)
```

```py
aspect = display[0] / display[1]
set_orthographic_matrix(-5 * aspect, 5 * aspect, -5, 5, -20, 20)
```

Do not transform the original vertices, but arguments to the `draw_cube` function:

```py
def draw_cube(vertices, edges):
    glBegin(GL_LINES)
    glColor3f(1, 1, 1)
    for edge in edges:
        for vertex in edge:
            glVertex3fv(vertices[vertex][:3])
    glEnd()
```

Pass the vertices and edges to the function if you want to draw a cube:

```py
draw_cube(vertices, edges)
```

If you want to transform the cube, copy the vertices, transform the copy of the vertices and finally bass the transformed vertices to `draw_cube`:

```py
v = np.copy(vertices)

# Translate along the x-axis
translation_matrix = np.array([
    [1, 0, 0, 1.5],
    [0, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1]
])
v = np.dot(v, translation_matrix.T)

# Perform isometric projection
isometric_matrix = np.array([
    [0.707, -0.408, 0.577, 0],
    [0, 0.816, 0.577, 0],
    [-0.707, -0.408, 0.577, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1]
])
v = np.dot(v, isometric_matrix)

draw_cube(v, edges)
```

---

Complete example:

[image]

```py
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
import numpy as np

vertices = np.array([
    (-1,-1,-1, 1), ( 1,-1,-1, 1), ( 1, 1,-1, 1), (-1, 1,-1, 1), 
    (-1,-1, 1, 1), ( 1,-1, 1, 1), ( 1, 1, 1, 1), (-1, 1, 1, 1)], dtype=np.float64)
edges = [(0,1), (1,2), (2,3), (3,0), (4,5), (5,6), (6,7), (7,4), (0,4), (1,5), (2,6), (3,7)]

axis_vertices = np.array([
    [0, 0, 0, 1],
    [4, 0, 0, 1],
    [0, 4, 0, 1],
    [0, 0, 4, 1]
], dtype=np.float64)

axis_edges = [
    (0, 1),
    (0, 2),
    (0, 3)
]

def draw_cube(vertices, edges):
    glBegin(GL_LINES)
    glColor3f(1, 1, 1)
    for edge in edges:
        for vertex in edge:
            glVertex3fv(vertices[vertex][:3])
    glEnd()

def draw_axes(axis_vertices):
    glBegin(GL_LINES)
    glColor3f(1, 0, 0)
    glVertex3fv(axis_vertices[0][:3])
    glVertex3fv(axis_vertices[1][:3])
    glColor3f(0, 1, 0)
    glVertex3fv(axis_vertices[0][:3])
    glVertex3fv(axis_vertices[2][:3])
    glColor3f(0, 0, 1)
    glVertex3fv(axis_vertices[0][:3])
    glVertex3fv(axis_vertices[3][:3])
    glEnd()

def set_orthographic_matrix(l, r, b, t, n, f):
    m = np.array([
        [2/(r-l), 0, 0, -(r+l)/(r-l)],
        [0, 2/(t-b), 0, -(t+b)/(t-b)],
        [0, 0, -2/(f-n), -(f+n)/(f-n)],
        [0, 0, 0, 1]
    ])
    glLoadMatrixd(m.T)

def main():
    pygame.init()
    display = (800, 600)
    pygame.display.set_mode(display, DOUBLEBUF | OPENGL)
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    
    aspect = display[0] / display[1]
    set_orthographic_matrix(-5 * aspect, 5 * aspect, -5, 5, -20, 20)

    run = True
    while run:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False    

        v = np.copy(vertices)

        # Translate along the x-axis
        translation_matrix = np.array([
            [1, 0, 0, 1.5],
            [0, 1, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 1, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 1]
        ])
        v = np.dot(v, translation_matrix.T)

        # Perform isometric projection
        isometric_matrix = np.array([
            [0.707, -0.408, 0.577, 0],
            [0, 0.816, 0.577, 0],
            [-0.707, -0.408, 0.577, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 1]
        ])
        v = np.dot(v, isometric_matrix)

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        draw_axes(np.dot(axis_vertices, isometric_matrix))
        draw_cube(v, edges)
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(100)

    pygame.quit()
    quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```